# Return a variable result of a function to an Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is my Ajax call :

```
$("#cover-input").change(function(){
var file_data = $("#cover-input").prop("files")[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("cover_file", file_data);
//kaherdin
$.ajax({
    url:  'update-cover',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'script',
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log('Likes error', err);
    }
});
    readURL_cover(this);
});
```

I've a function that basicly trim and upload a file on change.

```
 public  function  updateCover(Request $request) {
    $user = Sentinel::check();
    $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/users');

    if ($fileCover = $request->file('cover_file')) {
        $input_cover = time().'.'.$fileCover->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $img = Image::make($fileCover->getRealPath());
        $img->fit(1920, 555, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input_cover);
       // $user->cover = $input_cover;

        $response = $input_cover;          
        return $response;
    }
```

But this get me an error. I just want to get "input_cover" back to my ajax call so I can show the updated picture. 
If I change : $response = $input_cover to $response = [$input_cover]; it kinkds of work but the input is like : ["my_pic.jpg"] so it's not nice.

Comment: What is the error? You never appear to call the function in the PHP script.

Comment: Likes error Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

The call is made here : $.ajax({
    url:  'update-cover',

Comment: _But this get me an error_ Would you like to share with us what error you are getting or should we just make a few guesses??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a JsonResponse like so:

```
return response()->json(['input_cover' => $input_cover]);
```

Check this for responses in json and how they work https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses

Comment: Great ! And If I just need to the name of my variable ? I can do it in JS, it's the better way ?